# ffmpeg pipe out to stdout on windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, pipe

Hello I need to pipe output from ffmpeg to another program. It's works on my macOs with command:

```
ffmpeg -i C0333.MP4 -start_number 0  -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb48le pipe: | rgb2dng -i - -n 0 -o 'export/test-####.dng'
```

I have ported rgb2dng from Unix systems to Windows. But same command doesn't work. rgb2dng used stdin to read pipe:

```
    if (strcmp(ifn,"-")==0) {
        ifo = stdin;
    } else {
        ifo = fopen(ifn, "rb");
    }
```

Comment: You may need to reopen `stdin` in binary mode else it likes to mangle your data in Windows.

Comment: `-start_number 0` is being ignored because that's an option for the image demuxer/muxer and HLS muxer, but not rawvideo.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It has started work. But data looks corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use output option "-"

`-i - -y -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -f mp3 -`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).